# Set object terms for latest WooCommerce products and remove object terms for older ones

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, taxonomy-terms

I want to set the last 32 uploaded products in a certain category.

The function works but it doesn't remove the category from the older products, when new products are uploaded.

Here is the code:

```php
function add_category_to_product()
{

    $args = array(
        'post_type'   => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 32
    );

    $products = new WP_Query($args);
    $foundposts = $products->post_count;

    if ($products->have_posts()) {
        while ($products->have_posts()) {
            $products->the_post();

            
            if ($foundposts <= 32 && has_term(array(86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 83, 94, 95, 96, 84, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 80), 'product_cat', get_the_ID())) {
                wp_set_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 79, 'product_cat', true);
            } elseif ($foundposts <= 32 && has_term(array(51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 43, 60, 61, 62, 63, 45, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 48, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 44, 49), 'product_cat', get_the_ID())) { 
                wp_set_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 40, 'product_cat', true);
            } elseif ($foundposts <= 32 && has_term(array(128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 114, 115, 133, 134, 135, 136, 117, 118, 119, 137, 138, 139, 140), 'product_cat', get_the_ID())) {
                wp_set_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 112, 'product_cat', true);
            } elseif ($foundposts <= 32 && has_term(array(141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 125, 147, 148, 149, 150), 'product_cat', get_the_ID())) {
                wp_set_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 122, 'product_cat', true);
            } else {
                wp_remove_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 112, 'product_cat');
                wp_remove_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 122, 'product_cat');
                wp_remove_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 40, 'product_cat');
                wp_remove_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 79, 'product_cat');
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can see my mistake?

Comment: add to your args 'orderby'   => 'date',  'order' => 'ASC',

Comment: Tested it and uploaded another product, but the old product or in other words the 33rd product doesn't get the categorie removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your mistake:**

You use `'posts_per_page' => 32` and mention 'and for the other products', while the else condition is in the loop of those 32 current products...

**The solution:**

- Use [wc_get_products or WC_Product_Query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query)
- Since you actually want to apply a change for all products (unless you perform this function on a regular basis), just applying to the last 32 products will not suffice. So use `limit`, which accepts an integer: Maximum number of results to retrieve or `-1` for unlimited.
- `orderby` - Accepts a string: 'none', 'ID', 'name', 'type', 'rand', 'date', 'modified'.
- `order` - Accepts a string: 'DESC' or 'ASC'. Use with `orderby`.
- `return` - Accepts a string: `ids` or `objects.` Since we only need the productID against the product object, will `ids` suffice.
- **Note:** This way of making changes to products is effective when there are not a lot of products involved. If not, then a sql query is a much more efficient solution.

**WordPress functions used:**

- [wp_set_object_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_set_object_terms/)
- [wp_remove_object_terms()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remove_object_terms/)
- [has_term()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/)

So you get:

```php
// For x number of last products
$last_products = 32;

// Args
$args = array(
    'limit'     => -1,
    'orderby'   => 'date',
    'order'     => 'DESC',
    'return'    => 'ids',
);

// Get product IDs
$product_ids = wc_get_products( $args );

// Loop through
foreach( $product_ids as $key => $product_id ) {
    if ( ( $key + 1 ) <= $last_products ) {
        if ( has_term( array( 80, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 83, 94, 95, 96, 84, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103 ), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, 79, 'product_cat', true );
        } elseif ( has_term( array( 44, 49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 43, 60, 61, 62, 63, 45, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 48, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78 ), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, 40, 'product_cat', true );                
        } // etc..
    } else {
        if ( has_term( array ( 40, 79, 112, 122 ), 'product_cat', $product_id ) ) {
            wp_remove_object_terms( $product_id, 40, 'product_cat', true );
            wp_remove_object_terms( $product_id, 79, 'product_cat', true );
            wp_remove_object_terms( $product_id, 112, 'product_cat', true );
            wp_remove_object_terms( $product_id, 122, 'product_cat', true );
        }           
    }
}
```